# Visual Studio WPF XAML How to add different styles to multiple ComboBoxes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

**I have 2 ComboBoxes, I need to make one white and one black.**

I Right Click ComboBox > Edit Template > **Edit A Copy**.

There seems to be no difference in Creating a New Name or Apply to All, since it always Applies to All. The LinearGradientBrush code in the Main Template always overrides the Style in all ComboBoxes. **They all end up the same color.**

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

I Right Click ComboBox > Edit Template > **Create Empty**.

The Template is blank. I copy from the Microsoft ComboBox Template Example code, and it gives back errors.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplateDark" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color just use the Background Color property of the combobox

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom styles for different Comboboxes then define the style in Resource Dictinory file

add new file of type in project then add the following code

```
<Style x:Key="ComboboxRedStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger  Value="True">
              <Setter Property="BackGround" value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>



<Style x:Key="ComboboxBlackStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger  Value="True">
               <Setter Property="BackGround" value="Black"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Add the following code in app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/projectName;component/Resources/DesignResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/projectName;component/Resources/FocuseSettingResource.xaml"/>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

after including the code you can call the style for combobox where you need like below code

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboboxRedStyle}"Margin="251,38,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"   FontWeight="Bold"/>

                  <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboboxBlackStyle}"Margin="251,38,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"   FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Comment: I made the ResourceDictionary, (capitalize Value, decapitalize Ground, removed dxe, changed ComboBoxEdit to ComboBox). But I get error when calling the Style. "Key cannot be null.Parameter name: key"

Comment: I also imported the ResourceDictionary into the Main Window with <ResourceDictionary Source="ComboBoxStylesDictionary.xaml"/>

Comment: @wyzrd can you share your code which you are written and got error

Comment: I created a new project with 2 ComboBoxes and a Resource Dictionary for you to try. I get the "key cannot be null" error. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. https://www.dropbox.com/s/03oaw57b9xbn5t0/ComboBoxColors.zip?dl=0